# How can I improve the performance of this CSV parsing code?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, typed-arrays

I'm trying to parse a large CSV file ([this one](https://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/UnicodeData.txt), to be exact) into a `Map` from numbers to objects. Because the file is big and may take a while to download, the code parses it while it's still downloading, in order to prevent doing all the work at once, after the download finishes. Here's the code:

```js
const unicodeDataReader = (await fetch("data/ucd/UnicodeData.txt")).body.getReader();

const decoder = new TextDecoder();
let chunk, done;
let codePoint, column = 0, fieldBytes = [], codePointObj = {};
while ({ value: chunk, done } = await unicodeDataReader.read(), !done) {
  for (const byte of chunk) {
    if (byte === 0x3B) { // ;
      const a = new Uint8Array(fieldBytes);
      const field = decoder.decode(a);
      switch (column) {
        case 0:
          codePoint = Number.parseInt(field, 16);
          break;
        case 1:
          codePointObj.name = field;
          break;
        case 2:
          codePointObj.generalCategory = field;
          break;
      }
      fieldBytes.length = 0;
      column++;
    } else if (byte === 0x0A) { // \n
      ucd.codePoints.set(codePoint, codePointObj);
      fieldBytes.length = 0;
      column = 0;
      codePointObj = {};
    } else {
      fieldBytes.push(byte);
    }
  }
}
```

However, this code performs very poorly (even when downloading from `localhost`) and I don't know why. Chrome DevTools says that the lines that take the most time to execute are:

```js
const a = new Uint8Array(fieldBytes);
const field = decoder.decode(a);
```

The most weird thing about this is that this similar approach seems to work much better, but it may not work if a character is split between two chunks. (This doesn't happen with this file, because there are only ASCII characters, but I'm planning on adapting this code for other similar files.)

```js
const unicodeDataReader = (await fetch("data/ucd/UnicodeData.txt")).body.getReader();

const decoder = new TextDecoder();
let chunk, done;
let codePoint, column = 0, field = "", codePointObj = {};
while ({ value: chunk, done } = await unicodeDataReader.read(), !done) {
  for (const char of decoder.decode(chunk)) {
    if (char === ";") { // ;
      switch (column) {
        case 0:
          codePoint = Number.parseInt(field, 16);
          break;
        case 1:
          codePointObj.name = field;
          break;
        case 2:
          codePointObj.generalCategory = field;
          break;
      }
      field = "";
      column++;
    } else if (char === "\n") { // \n
      ucd.codePoints.set(codePoint, codePointObj);
      field = "";
      column = 0;
      codePointObj = {};
    } else {
      field += char;
    }
  }
}
```

I thought the problem was that `decoder.decode()` was being called too much, or that maybe creating an `Uint8Array` was slow, however that doesn't seem to be the issue, as this code runs very fast:

```js
const td = new TextDecoder();
const decoded= [];
for (let i=0;i<10000;i++) {
  // Generate a Uint8Array with 100 random bytes
  const a = new Uint8Array(function*(){for(let i=0;i<100;i++)yield Math.floor(256*Math.random())}());
  const b = [];
  for (const byte of a)
    b.push(byte);
  const c = new Uint8Array(b);
  decoded.push(td.decode(c));
}
```

How can I improve the performance of my code?

P.S.: I don't have network throttling enabled. The code is slow and the main thread freezes for seconds.

Answer (score -2):

You already test with streams? Look here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-stream

```
npm install csv-stream
```

```
var csv = require('csv-stream'),
var request = require('request');
 
// All of these arguments are optional.
var options = {
    delimiter : '\t', // default is ,
    endLine : '\n', // default is \n,
    columns : ['columnName1', 'columnName2'], // by default read the first line and use values found as columns
    columnOffset : 2, // default is 0
    escapeChar : '"', // default is an empty string
    enclosedChar : '"' // default is an empty string
}
 
var csvStream = csv.createStream(options);
request('http://mycsv.com/file.csv').pipe(csvStream)
    .on('error',function(err){
        console.error(err);
    })
    .on('header', function(columns) {
        console.log(columns);
    })
    .on('data',function(data){
        // outputs an object containing a set of key/value pair representing a line found in the csv file.
        console.log(data);
    })
    .on('column',function(key,value){
        // outputs the column name associated with the value found
        console.log('#' + key + ' = ' + value);
    })
```